# Qt Creator (Designer): Single text line with horizontal scrollbar

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit, qscrollarea, qscrollbar

How do I get a single text line with only a horizontal scollbar?

I think that's all there is to this question.

I've tried it with `QLineEdit` only or withing `QScrollArea`, with `QTextEdit` etc, and nothing was remotly close to working properly.

That's what I got so far:

[image]

It total it reads "Textexample", but the `QLineEdit` cuts it off and the `QScrollArea` doesn't provide a functional horizontal scrollbar.

In the end I'd like to have a single text line, with a horizontal scrollbar so with the scrollbar I can see everything that's inside the text line.

Thanks in advance. If more information is need, I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Can you please add a minimal reproducible example (as code) to your question to make your efforts visible and reproducible for us? THX :-)

Comment: since I work with the qt creator designer i can only provide you with html code :/

Comment: Fair point :-) Did you try to set the `horizontalScrollBarPolicy` property of the `QTextEdit` to `ScrollBarAlwaysOn`

Comment: ... and `lineWrapMode` to `NoWrap`?

Comment: I'll give it a try if i find it :D

Comment: @RYoda So if I had programmed everything with the creator itself, I coudl've just modified it with a single line in the code, but I can't find the option in the designer to do that and I don't think I can modify it in any other way :/

Comment: @Cpt.Crazy he told about replacing `QLineEdit` by `QTextEdit`

Comment: I am confused. Without seeing your Object inspector it is difficult to say what's the problem... See may screen shot in the answer...

Comment: Thanks. I was an idiot and looked into the `QLineEdit` options and not `QTextEdit`, my bad :D But now that i changed it, it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the fat properties of the `QTextEdit`:

[image]